# how can we create a nested form a single parent model in rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model, nested-forms

I have a `model` called `timesheet`. i wanted to have a nested form for this `timesheet` model. means i do not want to add any child `models` to it. Basically i want to have nested form for single `model(timesheet)`. 
when i click `add` `button` another `form` should come to the parent `model(timesheet)` similarly when we click `remove` the `form` should be removed. how can i do this? is there any `gem` to do this ?

i am using the self referential association.

getting the error:`Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :log_times association.`

```
<%= nested_form_for(@log_time, html: {:class => 'form-inline'}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :date %>
    <%= f.date_select :date, { order: [:day, :month, :year] } ,{:class => 'form-control' } %>
    <%= f.fields_for :log_time do |details| %>
      <%= details.label :date %>
      <%= details.date_select :date, { order: [:day, :month, :year] } ,{:class => 'form-control' } %>
      <%= details.link_to_remove "<i class='fa fa-minus'></i>Remove".html_safe,:class=>"btn btn-danger btn-sm" ,:style=>"color: white;"%>
    <%end %>
    <%= f.link_to_add "<i class='fa fa-plus'></i>Add".html_safe, :log_times, :class=>"btn btn-primary btn-sm", :id=>"",:style=>"" %>
    <%= f.button "Submit" ,:class=>"btn btn-primary  btn-sm" do%>
      <i class='fa fa-send-o'></i>Submit
    <%end%>



<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a self-referential association to your timesheet model:

```
class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Timesheet'
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Timesheet', foreign_key: 'parent_id'

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end
```

In the controller you can do:

```
@timesheet = Timesheet.new
@timesheet.children.build
```

Comment: do i need to create a field called "parent_id" ?, Can i call methods like @timesheeet.children? and child.parent?

Comment: You need to create a field `parent_id`. Yes, you can call `@timesheeet.children‌`​ and `child.parent`

Comment: getting the error : ArgumentError at /log_times/multiple_timesheets
Invalid association. Make sure that accepts_nested_attributes_for is used for :log_times association.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121163/discussion-between-john-and-rahul).